# What is purpose of the Tell A Friend "Info Page Link"

Tags: civievent

When setting up an event, in the Tell A Friend tab there is a Info Page Link. What is the purpose of that link? It does not store that information in the event table so I do not think it is even used.

Answer (score 3):

The tell a friend information is stored in another table called `civicrm_tell_friend`. The help text for the `Info Page Link` says -

> A link to this Event Information page is automatically included in the email sent to friends. If you ALSO want to include a link providing general information about your organization, enter that link here (e.g http://www.example.org/)

So basically its purpose should be to include an additional link(eg your organization) along with the message you send to the contacts from `Tell a Friend` form.

Comment: Except that the Share information on the confirmation email, only includes the default CiviCRM event link, not the Info Page Link

Comment: ok - this answer was just to provide an info of the expected functionality. If this is not happening then it could be an introduced bug preventing the intended workflow. Can you raise a bug if you're confident that this is not working as expected?

Comment: I tested this in the sandbox and got the same results. I went ahead and listed it as a bug. https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21173